# SendGrid mails are always in pending status

Tags: sendgrid

I am exploring to use SendGrid in one of my projects, I have followed the guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

after setting up the things, when I send emails, they are stuck at this point:

[image: mails pending]

There are few other mails that I tried to send to Gmail, they are still in pending status.

Comment: @moreirapontocom I had the same problem. For me, there was a banner on top of the website sayiing: `Hi. We haven?t seen you in a while. For your protection, we have closed this account. If you would like to use Twilio Sendgrid, please set up a new account here.`. Everything worked fine except for this issue. Eventually i had to create a new account. When creating a new account you can uncheck `Use email address as username`, and create a new account with the same email.

Comment: same problem, trying to move away from sendgrid.

Comment: Apparently, once you create a new account as @robvankeilegom has mentioned, you need to contact support to provide further details (they will guide you on what information they want) before they can 'do their thing in the background' and allow you to access your new account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that your account becomes inactive after a while. If you try to access the SendGrid after that period, you won't be able to send emails. You have to create a new account.

Answer (score 6):

In December 2022, creating a new account didn’t solve the issue for me. And there was a notice banner on the top after the new account was created:

> Your account is under review and we’d like to know a little more about you and how you intend to use Twilio SendGrid. Contact Us

So you have to **contact the support team of SendGrid** to remove the restrictions, which worked for me.

Comment: If that works, I think it is because of question threads like this. When this happened to me, I reached out to them, and the response was to create a new account.
Power of community.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new account solves this issue.
I used the existing email to create new account and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I have same phone number linked to blocked account, and when I tried to create new account, I was blocked instantly (on fresh new account)